# Print variable in a CDE dashboard using html or javascript

Tags: parameters, dashboard, pentaho

I have a dashboard with a popup slicer, but once I close the popup there is no way to tell which variables were selected, so I would like to display, above the chart, in a row, a path kind of line including all parameters I'm selecting in the slicer box.

I tried referencing them in a HTML layout position, like:
`${size}`, `${type}`, `${line}` and `${service}`, but it shows the text as written. No variables are parsed.

I also created a freeform component to use Javascript, but I see no data, and I can't figure out the function to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the more standard ways of doing that is by using a Text Component. In the expression field, you can use something like this:

```
function() {
  return "My Parameter: " + Dashboards.getParameterValue("myParam");
}
```

where `myParam` is the name of your parameter. You'll also want to add `myParam` to the listeners, so as to keep the text component in sync with the parameter.

The Freeform component would be a possibility as well, but it *really* is Free Form, you have to do everything yourself. We added that simply so we'd have an easy way to add arbitrary code to the CDF lifecycle. Using a Freeform Component you'd end up doing something like this in the Custom Chart Script (does it show we reused that property name from a chart?):

```
function() {

  $("#" + this.htmlObject).text("My parameter: " + Dashboards.getParameterValue("my Param"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a TON. It worked like a charm. I used the text component, though. Perfect for the task.

Comment: Yeah, like I said: The text component is the "correct" way of doing it. Since you had tried the freeform component, I just figured I'd throw that one in as well.